# NuGet Error: SecureChannelFailure (Object refence not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: nuget, monodevelop, nuget-package

I'm using Monodevelop on ubuntu and it seems as though the NuGet package manager extension is not working. When I check the sources I get the following error for https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

```
Error: SecureChannelFailure (Object refence not set to an instance of an object)
```

I've installed via flatpak.

Comment: This is a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57019) in Mono 5.0.

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't find that anywhere when I was searching! Managed to fix using: export MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=legacy

Comment: can you please explain where to use that command?

Comment: @santiagoarizti type it into the command line. If you're using linux press ctrl+alt+t to bring the command line up.

Comment: Make your solution an answer and accept it.